# Webpack serverless import typescipt only node_module errors "Cannot find module"

Tags: typescript, webpack, serverless

I try to import a ts-only node_module to a ts project that gets bundled and transpiled via webpack for a serverless function. When executing my code, the imported ts library cannot be found:
`"Error: Cannot find module '@jarvis/domain/carriers/schemas/carrier.schema'`

This has to to with the "domain" lib being typescript only. If I compile the lib first and import the compiled files it works fine. But with this I loose correct source map support so it is not a real option. If someone knows how to do this properly please let me know.

I have the following directory structure.

```
| packages
|-- domain (library written in typescript)
|-- -- package.json
|-- backend (written in typescript
|-- -- package.json
```

The package.json of the backend project imports the ts lib "domain" via file pointer

```
"dependencies": {
  "@jarvis/domain": "file:../domain/dist",
}
```

I bundle the backend app with webpack for a serverless lambda. This is my webpack.config.js

```
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");
const path = require("path");
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require("tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "eval-source-map" : "source-map",
  optimization: {
  // omitted for brevity
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".mjs", ".json", ".ts"],
    symlinks: true,
    cacheWithContext: false,
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({})],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
    path: path.join(__dirname, ".webpack"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  target: "node",
  node: {
    __dirname: true,
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      {
        test: /\.(tsx?)$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: [
          [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
            path.resolve(__dirname, ".serverless"),
            path.resolve(__dirname, ".webpack"),
          ],
        ],
        options: {
          transpileOnly: true,
          experimentalWatchApi: true,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```